# toggleClass with multi-level navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Right now, I'm trying to manipulate a menu just like [Microsoft.com](http://microsoft.com). I'm having an issue with being able to toggle the hidden unordered list in my links. I'll make a local fiddle in case you want to observe [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyneosy_/Pz5M6/)

**This is the HTML Markup :**

```
 <nav class="multi-menu">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="#">Link</a>
  <div class="sub-menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**This is the CSS Markup :**

```
 .multi-menu, .sub-menu {
  background: #34495e;
 }

 .multi-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .multi-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .sub-menu { 
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .sub-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
 }
```

**Here is the JQuery Markup**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".multi-menu li a").each(function() {
if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("parent");
   };
})

var menu = $(".multi-menu li a.parent");
 $(".parent").click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent(".sub-menu ul").toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: If this what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5M6/2/

Comment: @Tallmaris This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way that when it toggles the class that it can have more of a smooth animation? I've looked into it but it doesn't seem to execute correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need the class to simply hide and show then you can use `toggle` directly: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/, or the various `slideToggle`, `fadeToggle` etc. Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5M6/3/

Comment: @Tallmaris Okay awesome. One more question, if I use slideToggle to show the sub-menu, will that mess up the other nested navigation if goes more than two tiers?

Comment: You will need to play around with `find` and `children`, using the latter if you need only the first level of children... You can also use the `>` seletor that selects only immediate children. My advice is to limit the number of nested navigation to a max of 2 levels, also to make the user experience more pleasant.

Comment: No problems, I've put everything in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can remove the `div` and add the `sub-menu` class directly to the `ul` element:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then in the jQuery code, use `siblings` or `next` to find the submenu related to the parent link clicked:

```
$(".parent").on("click", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").toggleClass('open');
});
```

For animated visibility effects, you can use various jQuery methods, for example:

```
$(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
```